# Apache HTTPD server start wait time

Tags: docker, apache, kubernetes

Im trying to deploy apache "httpd" docker image to kubernetes cluster. I want the server to wait for 30 seconds before it starts . How to define that in the kubernetes deployment yaml file?

Can anyone help me out please.

Comment: What is the idea behind this? What's the problem you are trying to solve. https://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `initContainer` with a suitably configured wait time.

The setup would look something like this, added in the `spec` next to your `httpd` container:

```
initContainers:
- name: some-wait
  image: busybox:1.28
  command: ['sleep 30']
```

Instead of a static wait of 30 seconds, it would probably be better if you wait for a more specific condition, for instance another service being accessible. See the example at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/#init-containers-in-use for details.